# MySQL count how many tasks a user have before acting

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, it was hard to make a title, I hope I can make this clear.

I have the following table:

```
push_id int(11)
push_usr_id int(11)
push_account varchar(30)
pust_title varchar(128)
pust_contents varchar(254)
push_when datetime
```

These are reminders of tasks that will be sent via mobile push.
I have a cron that runs every minute like this:

SELECT * FROM push WHERE push_when <= NOW()

This gives me the total of reminders I have to push.

The problem is that a single user can have several reminders at the same time, it can have dozens even. I don't want to push dozens of messages to the user device (or devices), if a user has more than one reminder at the same time I want to send only one push message saying something like: "You have 12 tasks to do" or something like that instead of the standard reminder of the task.

I know the obvious is making another query for each reminder to obtain the number of reminders for that user id, but, as I said, this thing runs every minute. Is there a way of doing this without several queries? The table structure is not in production yet, I can still make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer here is the use of GROUP BY. In this case you'll want to group by push_usr_id.  Something like the below:

```
select push_usr_id, count(*) as Push_Num
  from yourtable
 where push_when <= now()
 group by push_usr_id;
```